# Should questions be closed as "general reference" on this site?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm new to moderating and I closed [this question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/how-does-the-ilr-scale-work?noredirect=1#comment1818_2105) as "general reference." This is a standard that is used on most other language sites; that if the answer to a question can be easily looked up on a single link, it is closed. Is this a standard that we want to follow on language learning, or should we *not* follow it here?

Comment: To be honest it seems Too Broad, I don't know about general reference though

Comment: In general, we should be less keen on closing questions and instead try to turn them into something more relevant and helpful. The goal of SE is to **learn from each other**, not, "Behave according to the rules or we will discourage you from asking other questions." The ILR question has been rephrased so it's no longer "general reference".